# Dynatree Lazy Load Not Working

Tags: jquery, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I'm creating a dynatree and loading the same data as provided in the example:

http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-lazy.html

Only my lazy node (Sub-item 2.3 (lazy)) does not show as expandable, and onLazyRead() never fires.

```
$("#tree").dynatree({
    title: "Lazy loading sample",
    autoFocus: false,
    initAjax: {
        url: "sample-data3.json"
    },
    onLazyRead: function(node){
        console.log("LAZY");
    }
});
```

The data:

http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-data3.json

is the exact same data as the example page loads. The lazy node looks like this:

```
{"title": "Sub-item 2.3 (lazy)", "isLazy": true }
```

but no expand icon is showing:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: do you see any errors in browser console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had a custom icons.gif file that was missing the lazy load icons.

Comment: Good catch! And thanks for posting the solution back!